# Find similar entries with interchangeable rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I do have a MySQL table with entries for NPCs. Each NPC has 3 ability-slots. Each slot has two possible values.

I am trying to find similar NPCs. Similar means the following: Each NPC can build the same ability-combinations with those 6 abilities. Slots are interchangable, but the a and b-value always stay together.

Example: In the following table the NPC 40 and 41 would be similar. NPC 42 would not be similar to them because it can't build the same ability-combinations, even tho the 6 spell IDs are the same:

NPC 40 and 41 could use abilities: 492+429+538;

NPC 42 could not because 492 and 429 are on the same slot.

```
NPC
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| id  | slot_1a | slot_1b | slot_2a | slot_2b | slot_3a | slot_3b |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| 39  |    384  |    202  |    389  |    392  |    459  |     278 |
| 40  |    429  |    535  |    492  |    357  |    538  |     536 |
| 41  |    492  |    357  |    429  |    535  |    538  |     536 |
| 42  |    492  |    429  |    357  |    535  |    538  |     536 |
+-----+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

If I am not mistaken there are 48 possible combinations for similar NPCs. Now I am wondering if there is a simpler solutions to find similar NPCs then checking all 48 combinations?

SQL Fiddle (new data): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c1aae/1

**Edit:** Forgot to mention, that the values of each slot can switch their position, too. That's probably the reason, why the @Kostas Mitsarakis does not work 100%.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: added a SQL Fiddle to the original post.

Comment: It works. You had forgotten to add a '2' to id 40 in column 'slot_1a' (it was 29 instead of 429).

Answer (score 1):

I am almost sure that there is a better way but you can try this. You have to check for each slot combination if matches with the other ones.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a81e6/1)

```
SELECT aa.npc_id, bb.npc_id
FROM npc AS aa, npc AS bb
WHERE 
( (
    aa.slot_1a = bb.slot_1a AND aa.slot_1b = bb.slot_1b) 
    OR (aa.slot_1a = bb.slot_2a AND aa.slot_1b = bb.slot_2b) 
    OR (aa.slot_1a = bb.slot_3a AND aa.slot_1b = bb.slot_3b) 
)
AND 
( (
    aa.slot_2a = bb.slot_1a AND aa.slot_2b = bb.slot_1b) 
    OR (aa.slot_2a = bb.slot_2a AND aa.slot_2b = bb.slot_2b) 
    OR (aa.slot_2a = bb.slot_3a AND aa.slot_2b = bb.slot_3b) 
)
AND 
( (
    aa.slot_3a = bb.slot_1a AND aa.slot_3b = bb.slot_1b) 
    OR (aa.slot_3a = bb.slot_2a AND aa.slot_3b = bb.slot_2b) 
    OR (aa.slot_3a = bb.slot_3a AND aa.slot_3b = bb.slot_3b) 
)
AND aa.npc_id != bb.npc_id;
```

Comment: re-checked with real data, sadly this solutions does not work 100%

Comment: Hm, could you provide a large sample of real data to an SQL Fiddel to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but this is how I ended solving it:

```
SELECT group_concat( npc_id separator ','),
@slot1:= concat_ws(',',least(slot_1a,slot_1b),greatest(slot_1a,slot_1b)) AS slot1,
@slot2:= concat_ws(',',least(slot_2a,slot_2b),greatest(slot_2a,slot_2b)) AS slot2,
@slot3:= concat_ws(',',least(slot_3a,slot_3b),greatest(slot_3a,slot_3b)) AS slot3,
@min:=least(least(@slot1,@slot2),@slot3) as min,
@max:=greatest(greatest(@slot1,@slot2),@slot3) as max,
@med:=(
CASE
    when @slot1 != @min and @slot1 != @max then @slot1
    when @slot2 != @min and @slot2 != @max then @slot2
    when @slot3 != @min and @slot3 != @max then @slot3
END
) AS med,
concat_ws(',',@min,@med,@max) AS move_set
FROM npc
GROUP by move_set
```